# How can I hide the "Actions" panel / tab / pane in Windows "Event Viewer"?

Tags: windows, windows-event-log, eventviewer

I want to get rid of the "Actions" panel in the Event Viewer.  It doesn't help me. I've made it as small as possible but I just want to hide it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Click View>Customize and uncheck the Action pane checkbox.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just uncheck "Display Action Pane"

[image: Just uncheck "Show Action Pane"]